# Sending multiple data to function/s

Tags: c

I am trying to send multiple data to a function which further receives the data and sends it to another function for database insertion. I have tried referencing the data using pointers but for some reason it does not receive the data as I want. The data to be sent is as follows:

```
void print_ethernet_data(const u_char *Buffer , int Size){

unsigned char dest_mac[6]; unsigned char src_mac[6];
struct ether_header *eth = (struct ether_header *)Buffer;

    printf( "\n");
    printf( "Ethernet Header\n");
    printf( "   |-Destination Address : %.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X \n", eth->dhost[0] , eth->dhost[1] , eth->dhost[2] , eth->dhost[3] , eth->dhost[4] , eth->dhost[5] );
    printf( "   |-Source Address      : %.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X \n", eth->shost[0] , eth->shost[1] , eth->shost[2] , eth->shost[3] , eth->shost[4] , eth->shost[5] );
    printf( "   |-Protocol            : %u \n",(unsigned short)eth->type);
    *dest_mac = &eth->dhost;
    *src_mac = &eth->shost;
    handledata(Buffer + header_size , Size - header_size, &dest_mac, &src_mac);  //This is the function called
}
```

Here `ether_header` is defined as:

```
struct ether_header {
    unsigned char dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    // Destination host address
    unsigned char shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    // Source host address
    unsigned short type;                    // IP? ARP? RARP? etc
};
```

The called function `handledata` is as follows:

```
void handledata(struct sniff_dns* dns, int size, unsigned char* dest_mac, unsigned char** src_mac)
{

    //RECEIVEING DATA HERE-------------------------------
    printf("DST_MAC = %.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X\n",dest_mac[0], dest_mac[1], dest_mac[2], dest_mac[3], dest_mac[4], dest_mac[5]);
    printf("SRC_MAC = %.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X\n",src_mac[0], src_mac[1], src_mac[2], src_mac[3], src_mac[4], src_mac[5]);
    insert_in_db(&dst_mac, &src_mac);    //How should I handle this function and its call?
}
```

The output I want is completely different than what I expect it to be. I have printed both the outputs and they are different. I guess the second one is pointing to the address of the array defined above in `eth->dhost` and `eth->shost`

**Output:**

```
|-Destination Address : E4:FC:82:FD:32:C1 
|-Source Address      : 58:49:3B:38:B5:11 
|-DST_MAC = 86:64:98:46:2E:7F   //They are different from the ones above
|-SRC_MAC = 4698648C:00:00:00:00:00 //This one too
```

I'd be grateful if somebody could help me through this. Also, How should I pass the data to `insert_in_db()` function and it's handling there? Thanks in advance

Comment: `unsigned char* dest_mac[6]` - this is an array of 6 `char *`, while presumably you want array of 6 chars instead.

Comment: @kfx my bad. Fixed the error about the array type, but the problem still remains

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `dest_mac` and `src_mac` as arrays and then tried to use them as a pointer which doesn't make sense. I'm guessing you want those variables to point to the data from the buffer. If that's the case, use a pointer instead of an array.

```
void print_ethernet_data(const u_char *Buffer , int Size){

unsigned char *dest_mac; unsigned char *src_mac;
struct ether_header *eth = (struct ether_header *)Buffer;

    printf( "\n");
    printf( "Ethernet Header\n");
    printf( "   |-Destination Address : %.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X \n", eth->dhost[0] , eth->dhost[1] , eth->dhost[2] , eth->dhost[3] , eth->dhost[4] , eth->dhost[5] );
    printf( "   |-Source Address      : %.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X \n", eth->shost[0] , eth->shost[1] , eth->shost[2] , eth->shost[3] , eth->shost[4] , eth->shost[5] );
    printf( "   |-Protocol            : %u \n",(unsigned short)eth->type);
    dest_mac = eth->dhost;
    src_mac = eth->shost;
    handledata(Buffer + header_size , Size - header_size, &dest_mac, &src_mac);  //This is the function called
}
```

And your other function also needs a fix for the `src_mac` variable since you defined it as a pointer to a pointer instead of just being a plain pointer to `char`.

```
void handledata(struct sniff_dns* dns, int size, unsigned char* dest_mac, unsigned char* src_mac)
{

    //RECEIVEING DATA HERE-------------------------------
    printf("DST_MAC = %.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X\n",dest_mac[0], dest_mac[1], dest_mac[2], dest_mac[3], dest_mac[4], dest_mac[5]);
    printf("SRC_MAC = %.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X\n",src_mac[0], src_mac[1], src_mac[2], src_mac[3], src_mac[4], src_mac[5]);

    insert_in_db(dst_mac, src_mac);    //How should I handle this function and its call?
}
```

And finally, on the call to the `insert_in_db` function, you can just pass the pointer instead of passing the address of the pointer. I think you should read about pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you use

```
struct ether_header *eth = (struct ether_header *)Buffer;
```

and this is just pointer conversion (originally `Buffer` is `const u_char`), but not data processing.

If your function receive array of bytes then conversion to `struct ether_header` is required.
So, if order of bytes in `Buffer` corresponds to required order in `dhost` (and/or `shost`) consider copying data with [memcpy function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Comment: Yes but that is because the `ether_header` makes a struct of the data in Buffer which is in Bytes. Unless that is not done, the correct structure to get `dhost` and `shost` does not happen.

Comment: @DevanshuMisra you can use `struct ether_header` as a type of function argument... what is the problem with this?

Comment: becuase I have to print the data at both the places. And Buffer has other data too, which is not displayed here. So memcpy will copy the whole Buffer to this struct, which is, in my honest opinion, not possible.

Comment: @NickS Wow, didnt think it that way. I think I can try that. Will update when done. Thanks. But these values are still to be sent to the `insert_in_db()` function.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of errors related to pointers. The overall recommendation is to improve your understanding how pointers work, and learn to use a debugger.

Error 1: In the function `handledata`, the type of parameter `src_mac` should be a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer.

Error 2: This code: `*dest_mac = &eth->dhost;` will assign only to the first element of the `dest_mac`. Also, it will assign the address of the `eth->dhost`, while you want to assign the value instead.

This would work correctly, as well as be simpler, for example:

```
void print_ethernet_data(const u_char *Buffer, int Size) {
    unsigned char* dest_mac;
    unsigned char* src_mac;
    struct ether_header *eth = (struct ether_header *)Buffer;
    dest_mac = eth->dhost;
    src_mac = eth->shost;
    handledata(Buffer + header_size , Size - header_size, dest_mac, src_mac);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the necessary improvements. This worked just fine. I am now working on handling `insert_in_db()`  function. And I would definitely go through the pointer concepts. Just that it gets a little difficult when working with different data types